# Calling getJson from hangouts api

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp, google-hangouts

Is it possible to use the $.getJSON from a google Hangout Window. I am trying to do it from a barely modified sample version but I can't get any response from the server.
http://pastebin.com/x8jXVceQ#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) you can just access a document via AJAX, if it is accessed through the same protocol and TCP port and is stored on the same domain.

If want to access a document from another domain, you can use [Cross-origin resource sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing). Therefore the site you want to get via AJAX has to provide the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` HTTP header like:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://hangout.google.com
```

(You have to replace `hangout.google.com` with the actual domain of the Google hangout window)

Comment: I finally did it! I did not have to use jsonp but had to add the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to the response header. Thank you very much for your help tampis.